# firebug like jquery implementation

Tags: jquery

I want to implement a firebug like highlight when my cursor hovers an element

```
$("*").mouseover(function()
{
    $(this).css({border:'1px solid blue'});
})
.mouseleave(function() 
{
    $(this).css({border: ''});
});
```

but it doesnt change the css when the cursor hovers an inner element, the outer element still has its style changed instead of reverting back to its original css due to `mouseleave()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do such heavy stuff on `*`. Use [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead.

```
$('body').delegate('*', 'mouseover mouseout', function (e) {
    if (this === e.target) {
        $(e.target).css('border', (e.type === 'mouseover' ? '1px solid blue' : ''));
    }
});
```

I haven't tested it, but my point is to use `.delegate`.

**Edit** Added suggestion by Crowder (thanks!)

Comment: I like how you've condensed things, and agree about `delegate` (was adding a `delegate` solution to my answer as you posted), but note that the above will re-call `css` repeatedly on the same element (`e.target`). If you have (say) a `ul` with an `li` with a `strong`, if the user hovers the `strong` element, your code will call `css` on the `strong` element three times (once for the `strong`, again for the `li`, and again for the `ul`). That's largely harmless in this case, but a lot of unnecessary work. @ianace, you'll want to add the `this === e.target` check.

Comment: Yes, I just jsbin'ed and checked, you are right. Funny, I can't still visualize why its doing this. have to look harder :) thanks btw http://jsbin.com/eveno4/8/edit

Comment: @Shrikant: No worries. :-) It's doing it because `delegate` is fantastic and actually does the bubbling calls, and `mouseover` and `mouseout` are bubbling events (so a `mouseover` on a child element is also seen at the parent element).

Comment: @Crowder, right but for the parent elements, it is a bubbled event right? not an event that *originated* on them, so `delegate` shouldn't pick it up.... oh wait! we are using the `*` selector which matches them all and the event is fired! damn! thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Like Noufal, my first thought was "better to do that with CSS's `:hover` pseudo-class" (unless you have to support IE6, which doesn't support `:hover` except on links), but I can't immediately think how you would handle making sure the ancestor elements didn't *also* have the border. And having the border on all the ancestors looks pretty ugly to me: http://jsbin.com/eveno4/2

For a JavaScript solution: You were close, but typically you'd use `mouseover` and `mouseout`, or use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, but not `mouseover` and `mouseleave` (not *usually*; there are places you would).

In this case, I'd probably use `mouseover` and `mouseout`, but only act on events actually triggered by the element in question (not bubbled ones):

```
$("*").mouseover(function(event)
{
  if (this === event.target) {
    $(this).css({border:'1px solid blue'});
  }
})
.mouseout(function(event) 
{
  if (this === event.target) {
    $(this).css({border:''});
  }
});
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/eveno4)

Note the use of [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) to make sure we're not processing a bubbled event.

Or, rather than hooking up a handler to *every element on the page*, hook up the handlers just on the `body` element and take advantage of the fact that they bubble, using [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
$(document.body).delegate("*", "mouseover", function(event)
{
  if (this === event.target) {
    $(this).css({border:'1px solid blue'});
  }
})
.delegate("*", "mouseout", function(event) 
{
  if (this === event.target) {
    $(this).css({border:''});
  }
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/eveno4/3)

(Or you could use `live`, it largely comes to the same thing.)

Comment: As far as I know, the `if` conditions are useless in the `delegate` example, as `this` is *always* equal to `event.target`.

Comment: @Shrikant: No, they do serve a purpose. Look at this without them: http://jsbin.com/eveno4/5

Comment: @Crowder My bad, I had this in mind when I was saying that http://jsbin.com/eveno4/6/edit (adopted from my answer)

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do something like

```
*:hover {
     border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

in your CSS rules rather than rely on Javascript?

*Update*. I just tried it and it seems to work reasonably well.

Comment: never thought of that, but would that solve the problem of not including the parent element being hovered also? i mean if i go to an inner element then the focus would be on the inner element not on the parent and thus not change its css

Comment: Well, the parent would get highlighted too but you might be able to find a narrower selector and use that. Also, It's not *as* distracting as it sounds.

Comment: How would you do that? (Reliably cross-browser, of course.) Target any element, but only one at a time? To my eyes, it looks terrible with the parents also having the border: http://jsbin.com/eveno4/2

Comment: You're right. There isn't a way (I can't think of any anyway). It doesn't look *that* bad to me but it's not perfect. I tried to get something better using opacity and background colours instead but couldn't manage.